# Clojurescript CSS in a JAR

Tags: css, clojurescript

I have a Clojurescript project (`lib-project`) which includes some CSS in `resources/css/`. When I do `lein install` the CSS is included in the JAR in `/css/`.
In another project (`main-project`) I have `lib-project` as a dependency. How do I access the CSS in `lib-project`'s JAR?
My aim is to package `lib-project` so that it is complete and not dependent upon external resources.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you asked for, but for the same goal: There's a Leiningen plugin for Twitter Bower, an web asset package manager

https://github.com/chlorinejs/lein-bower

`lein-bower` also supports resolving bower dependencies from jar dependencies.